# Spring Restemplate exception handling error description null - result is 500 null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I currently have a spring boot application (version - 2.1.8.RELEASE) which exposed rest webservice that provide some basic email functionality. I have added swagger component to it and can test the webservice through swagger UI interface. For example when I test the webservice through swagger UI and I don't input mandatory field such as mailfrom I got a error message that states emailfrom is missing with a status code which is what i am expecting.

But when the same scenario is carried out with a spring mvc project(client for web service - spring version 3.2.5.RELEASE) no description of the error is displayed as i was expecting to have the same behavior when testing with swagger Ui above. Please see screenshot result when carrying out integration test below the result is **500 null**:
[image]

Pleas find below spring boot application rest controller below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/email")
public class EmailController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailController.class);

    @Autowired
    SendMailService sendMailService;


    @ApiOperation(value = "This service send mail based on the information provided from EmailRequestDto", response = String.class)
    @PostMapping(value = "/sendMail")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> sendMail(@RequestBody EmailRequestDto emailRequestDto) {
        LOG.debug("calling method sendMail");

            sendMailService.sendEmail(emailRequestDto);

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Mail has been sent successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Please find below part of service class for sending e mail:

```
@Component
public class SendMailServiceImpl implements SendMailService {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SendMailServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void sendEmail(EmailRequestDto emailRequestDto)  {

        LOG.debug("calling method sendMail");

        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(emailRequestDto)) {


            MimeMessage msg = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
            // true = multipart message
            MimeMessageHelper helper;
            try {
                helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true);
                  helper.setFrom(emailRequestDto.getMailFrom());
                    helper.setTo(emailRequestDto.getMailTo().stream().toArray(String[]::new));
                    helper.setSubject(emailRequestDto.getSubject());
                    helper.setText(emailRequestDto.getEmailContent(), true);
//                  helper.addAttachment("my_photo.png", new ClassPathResource("android.png"));




                    javaMailSender.send(msg);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                 throw new ResponseStatusException(
                          HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Error occurred while send mail", e);
            }




        }

    }
```

Please find below my integration test for calling the web service from the client project:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:dummy-service-test-context.xml" })
public class SendMailServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void testService() {


        final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/email-service/email/sendMail";

        EmailRequestDto emailRequestDto = new EmailRequestDto();
//      emailRequestDto.setMailTo((Arrays.asList("dummy@gmail.com")));
//      emailRequestDto.setEmailContent("Dear Sir");
//      emailRequestDto.setMailFrom("dummy_38@hotmail.com");
//      emailRequestDto.setSubject("Sending Email subject");

        emailRequestDto.setMailTo(null);
        emailRequestDto.setEmailContent(null);
        emailRequestDto.setMailFrom(null);
        emailRequestDto.setSubject(null);

        HttpEntity<EmailRequestDto> request = new HttpEntity<>(emailRequestDto);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> es = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request,String.class);

//      ResponseEntity<?> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, ResponseEntity.class, new HashMap());

        Assert.assertTrue(es.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK));


    }

}
```

Please find my emailDto below:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ApiModel
public class EmailRequestDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<String> mailTo;
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Email address who is sending the mail", required = true)
@NonNull
private String mailFrom;
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Subject of the  mail", required = true)
@NonNull
private String subject;
@ApiModelProperty(value = "The content of the mail", required = true)
@NonNull
private String emailContent;
private List<String> bcc;
@ApiModelProperty(value = "This attribute identify if the mail content should be sent as html or plain text", required = true)
@NonNull
boolean fileHtml;
```

Can anyone point to me what i am doing wrong  and why i am getting 500 null please?

When I insert the dateFrom null purposely to force the application to fail in the spring boot tomcat log the exception is correct :

mailFrom is mandatory:

```
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: mailFrom is marked non-null but is null
```

But in my client integration test it is :

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
```

Comment: I dont think your server is running when you are running your test class, probably want to annotate your test class with @SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class})

Comment: Plus I would want to go with Mockito for integration testing , then going with Starting server and calling with restTemplate

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but the server is running because i can access the rest web service through swagger ui

Comment: you sure ? I mean after running you test case ? right click, run as Junit test ? and your server is running ?

Comment: ohh sorry i thought you  were talking about the spring boot application, no you right the client app is not running

Comment: Is your Spring Boot service outputting anything to the console when this happens? You can usually get the error log from the console when something like this happens.

Comment: I will check but the spring boot displaying the right error message when called from postman and swagger

Comment: @JeremySmith sorry for replying now, i have update the question with the error logs